# Need to convert String^ to char *

Tags: string, c++-cli, char

I am using the .NET DateTime to get the current date and time. I am converting it to a string to use as part of a file name. The problem is the OpenCV command to save an image requires a char * not a string type, and DateTime will only output a String^ type. How do I make this work? Heres the code not completed

```
String^ nowString = DateTime::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm");
        IplImage* toSave;
        CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
        toSave = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        cvSaveImage(nowString, toSave);
        cvReleaseImage(&toSave);
        cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
```

Comment: WHY THE ALL-CAPS?  ARE YOU SHOUTING?

Comment: Presumably his caps lock is stuck. That's also explain why he spelled ".net" without caps.

Comment: mistakenly hit caps lock

Comment: "mistakenly"?  I guess you mistakenly clicked submit, mistakenly forgetting to read before you submitted.  You don't need to explain or apologize.  Just fix it.  Many people do far worse things.

Comment: @S. Lott You don't fix a jackass by being one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert System::String to const char\*?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335426/how-to-convert-systemstring-to-const-char)

Answer (score 20):

Your best bet is to use `StringToHGlobalAnsi`. Here is complete code showing how its done and remembering to free the memory allocated.

```
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

void MethodName()
{
    String^ nowString = DateTime::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm");
    IntPtr ptrToNativeString = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(nowString);
    try
    {
        CvCapture* capture = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
        IplImage* toSave = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        cvSaveImage(static_cast<char*>(ptrToNativeString.ToPointer()), toSave);
        cvReleaseImage(&toSave);
        cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ptrToNativeString);
        throw;
    }
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal(ptrToNativeString);
}
```

You might want to rethink using a ':' character in the filename, as I don't believe windows likes this very much.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to use Marshal::FreeHGlobal() instead of Marshal::FreeCoTaskMem()? My MSDN help for StringToHGlobalAnsi() says use FreeHGlobal() to free the memory.

Comment: Yes, fair call; Edit made. I guess I got into the habit of using FreeCoTaskMem by default.

Comment: instead of writing the code for freeing the pointer here twice you could use finally. `try { ... } finally { Marshal::FreeHGlobal(...) }`

Answer (score 8):

Actually, I found the easiest way to get a `char *` from a `String^` is to use good ol' `sprintf()`. So in your case, you can simple do this:

```
char cNow[17] = { 0 };
String^ nowString = DateTime::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm");
if (nowString->Length < sizeof(cNow)) // make sure it fits & allow space for null terminator
  sprintf(cNow, "%s", nowString);
```

No need to call the `Marshal` functions!

**Update**

So it appears that VS 2015 adheres more closely to the C++11 standards, so using `sprintf()` with the .NET String won't work. The easiest way is to use the `marshal_as()` function like this:

Include these lines before your code:

```
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>
using namespace msclr::interop;
```

Then this should work:

```
char cNow[17] = { 0 };
String^ nowString = DateTime::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm");
string sNow = marshal_as<string>(nowString);
if (sNow.length() < sizeof(cNow)) // make sure it fits & allow space for null terminator
  sprintf(cNow, "%s", sNow.c_str());
```

Otherwise, if you don't want to use the `marshal_as()` function, you can copy the string character by character like this:

```
char cNow[17] = { 0 };
String^ nowString = DateTime::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm");
if (nowString->Length < sizeof(cNow)) // make sure it fits & allow space for null terminator
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nowString->Length; i++)
        cNow[i] = static_cast<char>(nowString[i]);
}
```

Comment: Well I was sceptical - nothing is ever that easy - but it does seem to work (with Visual Studio 2012).  Is there anything bad happening behind the scenes that means we shouldn't just do this?

Comment: @njplumridge I was skeptical as well when I learned about this technique. I'm guessing it's doing marshalling behind the scenes, but others may know more about it. This hides all the complexity though. I would do a check for the size before the sprintf() do prevent buffer overflows. See my edit above.

Comment: @njplumridge It is doing marshalling behind the scenes. See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11831686/1516125) for details.

Comment: Ha, I was about to add a link to that answer - you beat me to it :-)

Comment: Sadly under VS2015 it fails `'sprintf' : format string '%s' requires an argument of type 'char *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'System::String ^'`

Answer (score 1):

Random Googling got me this. Maybe someone can shorten it?

```
cli::array<char>^ bytes = Encoding::ASCII::GetBytes(nowString);
pin_ptr<char> pinned = &bytes[0];
std::string nativeString((char*)pinned, bytes->Length);
char const* chars = nativeString.c_str();
```

Edit: This is longer than the operations of the Marshal class, but works with more encodings. In your case, it sounds like the simpler `StringToHGlobalAnsi` approach will do everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about C++ interop and data marshalling.

Basically: you need to "cast" the .NET `String` to a C++ `TCHAR` array.

See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef4c3t39(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the `StringToXxxAnsi` functions in the [`Marshal` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal_members.aspx) to allocate a `char*` buffer, then the appropriate functions from the same class to free them.