# Why does printf work with managed Strings?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, marshalling, printf

we are currently digging through some really old C++/CLI-Code (Old Syntax .NET Beta) and were a bit surprised to see something like this:

```
System::String ^source("Test-String");
printf("%s", source);
```

The program correctly outputs

```
Test-String
```

We are wondering, why is it possible to pass the managed string source to `printf` - and more importantly: *Why does it work*? I don't expect it to be some convenience-feature by the compiler because the following doesn't work:

```
System::String ^source("Test-String");
char pDest[256];
strcpy(pDest, source);
```

This produces a (somehow expected) compiling error saying that `System::String^` can't be converted to `const char*`. So my only real explanation is that passing a managed reference to a va_list surpasses all compiler-checks and tricks the native code into using a pointer into the managed heap. Since `System::String` is represented similar to a `char`-Array in memory, `printf` may work. Or the compiler converts to a `pin_ptr` and passes that to `printf`.

I don't expect it to automatically marshal the `String^` to `char*`, because that would result in a bad memory leak without any reference to the actual memory address.

We know that this isn't a good solution and the various marshalling methods introduced by the later Visual Studio-Versions provide a way better approach but it would be very interesting to understand what is actually happening here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it is because the compiler is turning it into this IL:

```
call vararg int32 modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvCdecl) printf(int8 modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsSignUnspecifiedByte) modopt([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsConst)*, ..., string)
```

Which ends up as a pinvoke call to `printf`, so the runtime is being a little sneaky by marshalling it for you. You are still in a managed runtime, and the runtime will provide marhsalling as a service when it's needed.

---

Some notes:

It seems that `clr!GenericPInvokeCalliHelper` is doing this lifting on the x86 .NET 4 Workstation CLR.

> the following doesn't work

That's because that is straight C++. It has no chance to go through marshalling because it isn't needed.

Comment: So perhaps the question is, *why* is the compiler turning it into that IL? Since when is `printf` a managed function? Why is it P/Invoking it? Why isn't it calling it like any other native C++ function?

Comment: @CodyGray My suspicion is it's PInvoking it because the compiler sees something needs to go through the marshaller, first. I'll verify and write something more comprehensive in a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far! To me the only real difference between strcpy and sprintf concerning managed strings is the fact that sprintf takes a variable arg-list and strcpy does not. And maybe that's the reason for the IL-code.

Comment: Thanks again for the explaination! I'll stick to this as the answer. I'm pretty sure that it is turned into IL because of the varargs though, not because the compiler notices the need for marshalling - otherwise the strcpy would work as well.