# How to convert String^ to char array

Tags: string, visual-c++, c++-cli, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to convert String^ to char *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178023/need-to-convert-string-to-char)

I have been looking so long for this solution but I can't find nothing specific. I work in Visual Studio C++, windows forms app. I need to convert `String^` value into char array. 
I have stored value from `TextBox` in `String^`:

```
String^ target_str = targetTextBox->Text;

// lets say that input is "Need this string"
```

I need to convert this `String^` and get output similar to this:

```
char target[] = "Need this string";
```

If it is defined as `char target[]` it works but I want to get this value from `TextBox`.

I have tried marshaling but it didn't work. Is there any solution how to do this?

I have found how to convert `std::string` to `char` array so another way how to solve this is to convert `String^` to `std::string` but I have got problems with this too.

Comment: FYI this is not C++ but C++/CLI, a different language.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Retagged

Comment: I've added my solution to the original question, but basically I found that using `sprintf()` is the easiest way. No need to call the `Marshal` functions.

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to follow the examples set forth in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178023/need-to-convert-string-to-char).

Here's some sample code:

```
String^ test = L"I am a .Net string of type System::String";
IntPtr ptrToNativeString = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(test);
char* nativeString = static_cast<char*>(ptrToNativeString.ToPointer());
```

The reason for this is because a .Net string is obviously a GC'd object that's part of the Common Language Runtime, and you need to cross the CLI boundary by employing the InteropServices boundary.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this solution didn't work for me. I have tried marshalling but this solution don't mimics char[]. So i can't work with this char* as with char[]. Is there any idea how to convert String^ to std::string??

Comment: In C++ char* and char[] are equivalent, and therefore you can use a variable of type char* just as you would char[].  Have you tried taking the char* and passing it into whichever routine or method you're trying to call?

Comment: Thanks Maurice, you were right. Problem was that i was using 2d static array `array [x][sizeof(nativeString]`and value char* was not static as when i defined it as `char[] = "Static string"` I didn't notice that so when i use dynamic array it works. Thanks for help.

Comment: My pleasure.  Best of luck with what you're working on.

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++ there is equivalence between char[] and char* : at runtime char[] is no more than a char* pointer to the first element of the array.

So you can use you char* where a char[] is expected :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

void display(char s[])
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    String^ test = L"I am a .Net string of type System::String";
    IntPtr ptrToNativeString = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(test);
    char* nativeString = static_cast<char*>(ptrToNativeString.ToPointer());
    display(nativeString);
}
```

So I think you can accept Maurice's answer :)

Comment: Thank you both for the answer. You were right this conversion works. Problem was that i was using a static 2d array
`array [x][sizeof(nativeString]` 
and value char* was not static as when i defined it as 
`char[] = "Static string"`
It seems that i have to use dynamic array for this solution.

Thanks