# Convert a String^ to wstring C++

Tags: string, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, wstring

I programmed a little Application in C++. There is a ListBox in the UI. And I want to use the selected Item of ListBox for an Algorithm where I can use only wstrings.

All in all I have two questions:
-how can I convert my

```
    String^ curItem = listBox2->SelectedItem->ToString();
```

to a wstring test?

-What means the ^ in the code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665649/how-to-convert-string-to-char-array/13666083#13666083  Also, the ^ is a C++/CLI handle, similar to the * concept in standard C++.  It's called a handle, and means the object is a .Net object.

Comment: Is this *managed C++* a.k.a. C++/CLI?

Comment: @MauriceReeves I don't think that is a duplicate of that cause it's not about converting to a wstring! Thanks for the Information about ^

Comment: @ulidtko yeah it's a C++/CLI Application

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to convert String^ to char \*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178023/need-to-convert-string-to-char)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
std::wstring result = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>(curItem);
```

You'll also need header files to make that work:

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
```

---

What this `marshal_as` specialization looks like inside, for the curious:

```
#include <vcclr.h>
pin_ptr<WCHAR> content = PtrToStringChars(curItem);
std::wstring result(content, curItem->Length);
```

This works because `System::String` is stored as wide characters internally.  If you wanted a `std::string`, you'd have to perform Unicode conversion with e.g. `WideCharToMultiByte`.  Convenient that `marshal_as` handles all the details for you.

Comment: Thanks Ben Voigt - I will test it - give me 5 mins :-)

Comment: ben can u tell me from where I get marshal_as? Also I have include the header file

Comment: @user1557170: oops, you need a second header file.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm now a little bit confused - can u simply tell me which code I need ? I'm not a pro programmer like u

Comment: Just the first line, plus the two header files.  Everything below the divider just explains what `marshal_as` actually does inside.

Comment: should I need a speacial header file?

Comment: My compiler tells me that marshal_as is not defined

Comment: @user1557170: There's a namespace too.  Sorry for leaving that out.  You can also say `using namespace msclr::interop;`

Comment: yeah now it's working dude :-) Thanks for the great support you was a big help

Comment: can u tell me what is the best way to get an pro programmer like you?

Comment: @user1557170: Practice.  Follow tutorials written by experts.  Solve small problems.  Read other peoples' code that solves big problems.  Learn from it.  Write more code.  Read more code.  Ask what makes code good or bad and why.

Comment: May I ask, does msclr::interop::marshal_as require any cleanup?

Comment: @Robinson: There are two groups of conversions, ones that require cleanup require you to create a [`marshal_context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/marshal-context-class?view=msvc-160) instance that performs the cleanup when it goes out of scope.  Ones that don't require cleanup (because they return a smart object like `std::string` that knows how to clean itself up) use `marshal_as`.  You can't get this wrong unless you do something crazy like intentionally leak a `marshal_context` object.

Answer (score 0):

I flagged this as a duplicate, but here's the answer on how to get from `System.String^` to a `std::string`.

```
String^ test = L"I am a .Net string of type System::String";
IntPtr ptrToNativeString = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(test);
char* nativeString = static_cast<char*>(ptrToNativeString.ToPointer());
```

The trick is make sure you use Interop and marshalling, because you have to cross the boundary from managed code to non-managed code.

Comment: Yuck.  I refuse to reinvent this particular wheel, especially since the reinvention uses wrongly-named functions.  There's no `HGLOBAL` here at all.  Using that code is a documentation nightmare, because you have to write comments explaining what the not-an-HGLOBAL pointers actually are.

Comment: Actually, your answer is much better.  I need to look into the marshal_as method.  +1.  Thanks for pointing the way.

Comment: I really want some help eradicating (well, downvoting) every answer that suggests `StringToHGlobalAnsi` for this.  But that's a job for another day.

Comment: That'll be difficult, as this is the answer that even Microsoft recommends for this type of problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtohglobalansi.aspx

Comment: That's the `StringToHGlobalAnsi` page, they have to use that function.  By no means does an example somewhere indicate that it's the best way to perform the task.

Comment: By the way, this doesn't get you a wide string.

Comment: Right.  But if you do a search, that's one of the more...referenced pages.  For example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311259  Which I understand if your point.  :-D

Comment: Yes, which also mentions `marshal_as`.  They could do a lot better job of emphasizing which one is better, though.

Comment: I agree.  They make mention of when each method is mentioned, but do not indicate which is the best, preferred, etc.

Answer (score 0):

My version is:

```
Platform::String^ str = L"my text";

std::wstring wstring = str->Data();
```

Comment: I get ```error C2039: 'Data' : is not a member of 'System::String'```

Comment: This work on WinRT with `C++/CX` not on the older CLR with `C++/CLI`.

Comment: I like this, because this is straight forward: `String^` is in UTF16, and if `std::wstring` should also remain in UTF16 - there is no conversion needed just plain old copy of the characters. Voted Up.

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio 2015, just do this:

```
String^ s = "Bonjour!";
```

**C++/CLI**

```
#include <vcclr.h>
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> ptr = PtrToStringChars(s);
```

**C++/CX**

```
const wchart_t* ptr = s->Data();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to microsoft:

Ref [How to: Convert System::String to Standard String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-convert-system-string-to-standard-string?view=msvc-160)

> You can convert a String to std::string or std::wstring, without using PtrToStringChars in Vcclr.h.

```
// convert_system_string.cpp
// compile with: /clr
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace System;

void MarshalString ( String ^ s, string& os ) {
   using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
   const char* chars =
      (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(s)).ToPointer();
   os = chars;
   Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
}

void MarshalString ( String ^ s, wstring& os ) {
   using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
   const wchar_t* chars =
      (const wchar_t*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(s)).ToPointer();
   os = chars;
   Marshal::FreeHGlobal(IntPtr((void*)chars));
}

int main() {
   string a = "test";
   wstring b = L"test2";
   String ^ c = gcnew String("abcd");

   cout << a << endl;
   MarshalString(c, a);
   c = "efgh";
   MarshalString(c, b);
   cout << a << endl;
   wcout << b << endl;
}
```

output:

```
test
abcd
efgh
```