# Solutiousing system function to run bat file with arg from vc++

Tags: c++, function, batch-file, system

I am new in `visual c++` and I am practicing to develop very simple application.

I am still learning so please guide me.

I am trying to run a `batch file` withing visual c++ and need to add an `arg`after it.

```
String ^ arg = textBox1->Text;

system("file.bat"); // how can I add my arg here?
```

the arg depends on user's input from textbox.

Thank you very much in advance...

solution:

String ^ arg = textBox1->Text;
Process::Start("C:\file.bat", arg);

Comment: `String ^` is a C++ .NET idiom (managed string), are you using the .NET platform in C++ and if so can you use `Process.Start`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1 .. ?

Comment: Process::Start("file.bat", arg); does not work

Comment: What errors are you getting? "does not work" how? Is it in the batch file, i.e. the batch file is not receiving the proper arguments from the `arg` variable or just not running at all? Make sure when you do `Process::Start("file.bat", arg);` that `"file.bat"` can be found by your executable..

Comment: The batch file is being found because I can see it running. This batch file will open a small java program. there is no output from this program because there is no arg when the batch file was executed.

Comment: You're using a .NET `String^` which is a managed type and want to use it as a `char*` in the `system` command, to do this you'll need to marshal it from a .NET type to a non managed type (here's a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665649/how-to-convert-string-to-char-array ..). Also, what specifically about the `Process::Start` did not work, you say "there is no arg" but what specifically does that mean (the `arg` variable has nothing in it? it's not getting passed to the `file.bat`)?

Comment: Hi, it works now. I had to move the executable to the same folder as the source file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think `system("file.bat " + arg)` will work?

Comment: Hi, it didn't work. I got an error that the arg cannot be converted to const char. How can i convert the string to char?

Comment: As mentioned by @txtechhelp, you may be using the managed version of C++ in .NET. In this case, using the Process.Start should be a better solution. You can first try to fire up cmd.exe and manually type in the command, e.g., >>file.bat some_arguments, to make sure there is no problem with your batch file. Then you can try to replace the arg as a constant string, e.g., Process::Start("file.bat", "some_argument") to see if it works. Also note that, if there are spaces in your arguments, you need to surround it with double quote, e.g., Process::Start("file.bat", "\"some arguments\"");

Comment: Hi, I already replaced the arg to some value but still it doesn't work. I tried to get the value of arg by displaying it MessageBox::Show(arg); and it is ok. I get whatever I input in the textbox but it does not work with Process.Start method. There is no problem in the batch file as it is working from the console. I will just keep on trying, also reading now from this website for references.

Comment: Is that because of the path problem, i.e., when you run file.bat in command window, you are in the path where file.bat resides but when you run file.bat from code, the default path is your program's path. Another workaround is to generate another batch file on the fly containing the arguments and then you call the new batch file without arguments. For example, you generate a file named run_file1.bat which contains "file1.bat some_arguments".

Comment: Hi, the path is correct. I can see the batch file is running without an arg so it doesn't do anything.... example is that, if the arg is 1 then the batch will find something... in this case there is no output from the batch file.

Comment: if you "got an error that the arg cannot be converted to const char.", try system((string("file.bat ") + str).c_str());

Comment: How is the above small workaround works?    (Another workaround is to generate another batch file on the fly containing the arguments and then you call the new batch file without arguments. For example, you can generate a file named run_file1.bat which contains "file1.bat some_arguments")

Comment: Hi, you are right. I moved the executable to the same directory as the source file i am reading, works now. Thanks

Comment: That's great! Good luck for your project~

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "*.txt";
    system((string("dir ") + str).c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

and this works

Comment: Sorry for my stupidity, but i don't know how to implement your code onto my visual c++ windows form :(

Comment: The string with system function shows the string conversion operation. All other are not important